# Mongoose Query: how to find object array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If you send json data in the following format, the server tries to go through the item document of mongodb and write the code that returns the data with the same userId and exactly the same json data received by itemTag.

**I have this schema:**

```
var subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  main:Number,
  sub:Number,
  color:Number
},{ _id : false });

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    userId:String,
    date:String,
    itemTag: [subSchema]
}, { versionKey: false });
```

---

**db data :**

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("58ba81eea341c37ed7268703"),
   "date" : "20170304_175923", 
   "userId" : "aaa", 
   "itemTag" : [ 
       { 
           "main" : 3, 
           "sub" : 7,  
           "color" : 1
       }, { 
           "main" : 3, 
           "sub" : 1,  
           "color" : 11
       }, { 
           "main" : 4, 
           "sub" : 4,  
           "color" : 1
       }, {
           "main" : 5, 
           "sub" : 2,  
           "color" : 1
       } 
    ] 
},
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("58ba81eea341c37ed7268723"),
   "date" : "20170305_125923", 
   "userId" : "aaa", 
   "itemTag" : [ 
       { 
           "main" : 3, 
           "sub" : 7,  
           "color" : 1

       }, { 
           "main" : 2, 
           "sub" : 2,
           "color" : 2
       } 
    ] 
}
```

**and client send json data  : ** 
server get 
req.body.userId
req.body.itemTag

```
{ 
    "userId":"aaa",
    "itemTag":[{
        "main":3,
        "sub":7,
        "color":1
    },{
        "main":4,
        "sub":4,
        "color":1
    }]
}
```

**and i want get :**

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("58ba81eea341c37ed7268703"),
   "date" : "20170304_175923", 
   "userId" : "aaa", 
   "itemTag" : [ 
       { 
           "main" : 3, 
           "sub" : 7,  
           "color" : 1
       }, { 
           "main" : 3, 
           "sub" : 1,  
           "color" : 11
       }, { 
           "main" : 4, 
           "sub" : 4,  
           "color" : 1
       }, {
           "main" : 5, 
           "sub" : 2,  
           "color" : 1
       } 
    ] 
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to achieve, can you explain again?

Comment: I want to find the same value in the db as the following itemTag array.
{
"ItemTag": [{
        "Main": 3,
        "Sub": 7,
        "Color": 1
    }, {
        "Main": 3,
        "Sub": 1,
        "Color": 11
    }]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below find query. The query uses `$all` with `$elemMatch` to return rows when there is entry for each of the values in the array.

```
var rItemTag = req.body.itemTag
var qItemTag = rItemTag.map(value => ({"elemMatch": value}));
db.collection.find({itemTag: {$all: qItemTag}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
   db.collection.find(
        {"userId" : req.body.userId,"itemTag.main" : req.body.itemTag},
        {itemTag : 1,userId:1})
        .sort(sortQuery)
        .skip(skipPage)
        .limit(16)
```

OR

```
 db.collection.find(
        {"userId" : req.body.userId,"itemTag":{ "$elemMatch" : {main : req.body.itemTag}}},
        {itemTag : 1,userId:1})
        .sort(sortQuery)
        .skip(skipPage)
        .limit(16)



//Note : In collection you need to write your collectionName
```

3 ) - If you want a specific elements from array

```
db.collection.find(
  {"userId" : req.body.userId,"itemTag":{ "$elemMatch" : {main : req.body.itemTag}}},
     {"itemTag.$.main"  : 1,userId:1})
     .sort(sortQuery)
    .skip(skipPage)
    .limit(16)
```

Comment: thanks.. but i got this message : {
  "message": "Cast to number failed for value \"[ { main: 3, sub: 7, color: 1 }, { main: 4, sub: 4, color: 1 } ]\" at path \"main\" for model \"Item\"",
  "name": "CastError",
  "stringValue": "\"[ { main: 3, sub: 7, color: 1 }, { main: 4, sub: 4, color: 1 } ]\"",
  "kind": "number",

Comment: Please post what query you are execute ,, and make sure that all documents fields( "main" , "sub" and "color"  are number field)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you should use:

`itemTag.$.main` syntax

For getting first item in the array you can use:

```
itemTag.$0.main
```

For second item in the array:

```
itemTag.$1.main
```

and so on.......